# Unable to change values in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When I load some of the values in my Rails database and change their value,

```
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: 0, column2: true, ...>
x.column1 = nil # => nil
x.column2 = nil # => nil
x.save! # => true
# byebug output from my after_save callback which can modify these values
[117, 120] in /home/sam/mina-NQA/releases/23/app/models/publisher.rb
   117:
   118:   def set_recommendation
   119:     byebug
=> 120:     return nil if self.column1
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: nil, column2: nil, ...>
```

either reloading the same value or viewing the MyModel#show page reverts the values!

```
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: 0, column2: true, ...> # !!!
```

Why won't my changes persist? Edit: byebug shows my changes aren't ever applied, and this isn't about persistence. Why won't my changes apply?

---

I do have an after_save callback `after_save :set_column1`. But I feel confident it is not causing my issue because it contains a line like `return nil unless self.column2`. I do have a `before_save :create_sub_model`, which only creates nested model. I do have filters, but none which affect MyModel#show and none which update `column1` or `column2`.

The columns do not have default values. From `db/schema.rb`:

```
t.integer  "column1",  limit: 4
t.boolean  "column2",  limit: 1
```

---

I've also tried updating the column without saving:

```
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: 0, column2: true, ...>
x.update_column(:column1, nil) # => true
x.update_column(:column2, nil) # => true
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: nil, column2: nil, ...>
x = MyModel.find(123) 
# => #<MyModel id: 123, column1: 0, column2: true, ...> #!!!
```

Is there a function in Rails/ActiveRecord to ask: 'What are all the things that happen upon loading this?' (There is no such information in my `production.log`.)

---

```bash
ruby -v # => ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
rails -v # => Rails 4.2.1
mysql # => Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution
```

Comment: hey have you check default value of column2?? it might be `true` so.

Comment: @VishalJAIN A valid question, but no. I'll update the question now to reflect.

Comment: use byebug gem and use to see all backtrace and kindly put it here

Comment: @Sam also check if there any method is override in model of name `column2` because code is looking good.

Comment: If you inspect `x` just after `x.save!`, does it have the `nil` values? If not, your `after_save` is most likely the culprit.

Comment: @RajarshiDas Added byebug output, shows the value is never kept. @VishalJAIN Looked in my_model.rb -> no overrides. @Drenmi rails console has nil values for a second, then doesn't. UI view shows the same. byebug console has nil values until I `quit` and return to it.

Comment: Sam byebug should go to rails modules and all use `step `and try to debug it by may be attribute value assign will show something that kindly paste here

Comment: @RajarshiDas Can you please be more specific? I put the command into my `after_save`. Do I need to override `self.column1=` method to drop byebug in there?

Answer (score 0):

When you call save on an ActiveRecord object, other than the save callbacks (before_save, after_save), the update callbacks are also triggered. Do look into update(before & after) callbacks, if any.

Comment: Sorry, looks like that's not it. Please see the comments.